# Eclipse plugin dependency out of sync

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

When adding a plugin to an eclipse project as a dependency. The Dependencies tab says: (out of sync) for a specific plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to go to Preferences->Pug-in development -> Target Platform -> click the Reload... button